# How to use BroadcastReceivers in a Flex Mobile App?

Tags: apache-flex, android-intent, flash-builder, broadcastreceiver, air-native-extension

I am new to how Flex Mobile apps work, so please be descriptive in your replies.

I am trying to make a Flex Mobile app for the Android that is able to receive an intent from a service app that I have created.  The intent has a string attached to it and it is very important that my app gets that information.  However, I can’t seem to figure out how to make my Flex app receive intents sent by the Service app.

So far I have tried making the app pause in the native Android side for 3 seconds in the hopes that this would allow enough time for the onReceive() to be called.  This did not work.

Below is my code.  I appreciate your help.

The WiFi function sends an intent to the Service to activate the WiFi on the Android.

The WiFi_info function is supposed to return the data that is attached to the intent that this app will receive.

**ANESimpleApp.as - The ActionScript Library**

```
package com.example.anesimpleapp
{
    import flash.external.ExtensionContext;

    public class ANESimpleApp
    {
        // This will hold the context for the Native Android side of the plugin
        private var context:ExtensionContext;

        // Get a context of the ANE
        public function ANESimpleApp()
        {
            // Checks if the context was already setup
            if(!context)
            {
                context = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext("com.example.anesimpleapp", null);
            }
        }

        // Turn On/Off the Wifi
        public function WiFi(): void
        {
            context.call("WiFi", null);
        }

        // Get WiFi information
        public function WiFi_Info(): String
        {
            return String (context.call("WiFi_info", null));
        }
    }
}
```

**WiFi_info.java - The Native Android Code**

```
public class WiFi_info implements FREFunction {

    // This will retrieve information about the WiFi network the phone is currently connected to
    public String connectionData = "EMPTY";

    // This is used to reference the string value describing the WiFi network the phone is currently connected to.
    public final String KEY_WiFi_Info = "Update_WiFi_Info";

    // The expected intent
    public final String WiFi_Data = "com.example.Obtain_WiFi_Data";

    // Created a Runnable object
    Runnable myRun;


    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] object) {

        // The runnable object will be used to allow enough time for the BroadcastReceiver to set itself up
        myRun = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                // Causes this activity to wait 3 second.
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };


        // Sets up intent filter and BroadcastReceiver

        // This intent filter will allow the application to receive certain intents
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

        // This allows the application to receive data about the WiFi
        filter.addAction(WiFi_Data);

        // Registers the BroadcastReceiver onReceive() in this app
        context.getActivity().registerReceiver(mybroadcast, filter);


        // Generates a 3 second pause
        Thread myThread = new Thread(myRun);
        myThread.start();


        // Returns the information obtained from onReceive()

        // This will be used to hold the value returned from the function
        FREObject returnValue = null;

        try {
            // Obtains a string containing information about the WiFi network the phone is
            // currently connected to.
            returnValue = FREObject.newObject(connectionData);

        } catch (FREWrongThreadException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();

            return null;
        }

       // Unregisters the BroadcastReceiver (Don't want any leaked receivers)
       context.getActivity().unregisterReceiver(mybroadcast);

       // Returns value
       return returnValue;
    }


     // Receives the intent and places extra in class variable
     public BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver()
     {
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
         {
             if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(WiFi_Data))
             {
                 connectionData = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_WiFi_Info);
             }
         }
    };
}
```

**ANESimpleAppTestHomeView.mxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" title="HomeView">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.example.anesimpleapp.ANESimpleApp;

            [Bindable(event="UpdateTime")]
            private function WifiUpdate(): String
            {
                var ane:ANESimpleApp = new ANESimpleApp();
                return ane.WiFi_info();
            }

            public function button1_WiFiActivation(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                var ane:ANESimpleApp = new ANESimpleApp();
                ane.WiFi();
            }

            public function button2_WiFiUpdater(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                dispatchEvent(new Event("UpdateTime"));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
        <s:VGroup>
            <s:HGroup>
                <s:Button id="button1" 
                    x="25"
                    y="27" 
                    label="WiFi" 
                    click="button1_WiFiActivation(event)"/>

                <s:Button id="button2" 
                    x="25"
                    y="27" 
                    label="WiFi Info" 
                    click="button2_WiFiUpdater(event)"/>
            </s:HGroup>

            <s:TextArea id="WiFiInfo"
                width="65%" 
                editable="false" 
                borderVisible="false" 
                contentBackgroundColor="0xFFFFFF" 
                contentBackgroundAlpha="0" 
                height="400"
                text="{WifiUpdate()}"/>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:View>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code won't correctly pause for the 3 seconds. It looks as though you are starting another thread to do the delay which will mean your code will register and unregister the receiver before any actions can be taken.

It would be better to not use the delay at all and instead unregister the receiver in the actual BroadcastReceiver onReceive function. To do this you might need to store a reference to the context in your extension class **Extension.context** (though you probably are doing this already).

Also I suggest you break out the BroadcastReceiver into a separate class just to keep the code clearer and you should reference it from somewhere more global than a FREFunction, eg in your FREContext. I'll just write some psuedo code here to give you an idea:

Extension:

```
public class ANEExtension implements FREContext 
{
    public static FREContext context;

    public FREContext createContext(String arg0) 
    {
        context = new ANEContext();
        return context;
    }

    // Other functions...
}
```

Context:

```
public class ANEContext implements FREContext 
{
    public WifiReceiver receiver = null;

    public void registerWifiReceiver()
    {
        if (receiver == null)
        {
            receiver = new WifiReceiver();
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction("com.example.Obtain_WiFi_Data");
            getActivity().registerReceiver( receiver, filter );
        }
    }

    public void unregisterWifiReceiver()
    {
        if (receiver != null)
        {
            getActivity().unregisterReceiver( receiver );
            receiver = null;
        }
    }

    // .. Map<> getFunctions etc...
}
```

Function class:

```
public class WiFi_info implements FREFunction 
{
    @Override
    public FREObject call(FREContext context, FREObject[] object) 
    {
        ((ANEContext)context).registerWifiReceiver();

        // return stuff...
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Receiver class:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(WiFi_Data))
        {
            connectionData = intent.getStringExtra(KEY_WiFi_Info);

            //
            // Return Data
            if (ANEExtension.context)
            {
                ANEExtension.context.dispatchStatusEventAsync( 
                    "some:event:type", 
                    connectionData 
                );
            }
            //
            //


            ((ANEContext)ANEExtension.context).unregisterWifiReceiver();
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit: Adding a listener for the status events on the actionscript side**

The following is all AS3 code summarising the important parts of receiving a status event from the native code.

```
public class WifiExtension extends EventDispatcher
{
    public static const EXT_CONTEXT_ID : String = "the.extension.id";

    public function WifiExtension()
    {
        _extContext = ExtensionContext.createExtensionContext( EXT_CONTEXT_ID, null );
        _extContext.addEventListener( StatusEvent.STATUS, extension_statusHandler, false, 0, true ); 
    }

    private function extension_statusHandler( event:StatusEvent ):void
    {
        switch (event.code)
        {
            case "some:event:type":
                trace( "The data from the native code = " + event.level );

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I appreciate your response, and I am sorry I did not reply sooner.  I tried your idea, but unfortunately it did not work.  Furthermore, in the BroadcastReceiver you created, you did not send the string you obtained from the received intent to the WiFi_info() function so it could be passed to the user, which is what I need the ANE to do.  Do you have any other ideas I can try?

Comment: What exactly didn't work, I use this exact technique in several of my own ANE's. With regards to sending the data back, you can't send it back to the function, you'll need to use an asynchronous event to send it back to the Actionscript. I'll edit the answer to show an example

Comment: I meant that the process of sending the data to the ActionScript side did not work.  I also tried what you suggested, sending the data over as part of an event.  However, this did not work.  I am still very new to ActionScript, so I may have failed to implement this properly.  Could you please provide an example of how to send the data through an event?

Comment: Okay, I've updated to show a summary of the event dispatching. You might need to add some logging into your native code to see which parts you are reaching and whether you are actually getting to the receiver or not.

Comment: I used your example, but that did not work.  I used the debugger to see if it was registering the BroadcastReceiver and if the event handler was being called.  As far as I can tell, the BroadcastReceiver might have been set (I say might because I could not go into the Java native code to see that line of code execute), but the event handler is never called.  Meaning an event from the BroadcastReceiver was never dispatched.  This leads me to believe that the BroadcastReceiver was not set.

Comment: You said you use this sort of method all of the time and that it works for you.  I am new to ActionScript and building Flex Mobile Apps, so it is possible I forgot something fundamental to this ANE process.  Could you please tell me the process by which you did this?

Comment: I suggest you put some Log calls in your Java code and use adb logcat to see if your native code is getting called. It's rudimentary but simple.

Comment: It's an obvious one, but I just wanted to check you aren't using "com.example.Obtain_WiFi_Data" but actually replacing that with an action you know is being handled in your application and that you have permission to receive?

Comment: I am not using the intent name "com.example.Obtain_WiFi_Data".  I am using an intent name that I created, so I know that I have access to it.  I also know that what I am doing will work because I did this with two eclipse-made android apps before.  However, I wanted to make use of some of the functionality available to Flex Mobile Apps. For now, I am going to try SharedPreferences and the MySQL Lite Database.  Hopefully those will work.  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: Well the technique definitely works but can't really help you any further. You really should try adding some Log.d outputs and watching the logs to see where your code is failing. Good luck